# Playstation Pulse headset bluetooth compatibility

Tags: ps3

Is Playstation Pulse's Bluetooth compatible with mobile devices?

I saw an audio jack connected to a mobile device, but so far I haven't seen that you can connect it to a mobile device via Bluetooth.

I want to buy it but I want to verify if it is Bluetooth-compatible with mobile devices.

Comment: Bluetooth is bluetooth.  It's an industry standard.

Comment: @fbueckert well said. To OP, just like USB devices, bluetooth devices are always compatible, as long as the connection makes practical sense (ie, connecting a bluetooth printer to a mobile with no printer support makes no sense).